# how to enumerate through multiple digital certificates in .net

Tags: c#, ssl

What is the best way to enumerate through multiple certificates in an exe.
I used the following code

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(filePath);
var certificationCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(certificate);
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in certificationCollection) {
```

But this code only return the first certificate if the exe contains more than one certificate.

Example : SHA1 , SHA256

Comment: Is each certificate a different filename?  You are reading only one file.

Comment: two digital certificate (SHA1 , SHA256) added to the same exe file

Comment: "filepath" is the filename for each certificate so you need to read two files and put into a single Collection.

Comment: I ended up using pInvoke to read all the digital certificate embedded in the exe.